# Can't find the adobe acrobat 10.0 type library (2020)

Tags: excel, vba, adobe

I am trying to use VBA to read some text from a pdf.

I read that I need to reference the library, Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library. So I downloaded the Acrobat DC SDK for windows from [download page](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/sdk/eula.html). However I have looked through the files but I can't find the Adobe Acrobat 10.0 dll. Where can I find this dll?

Comment: `\Acrobat 10 SDK\Version 1\InterAppCommunicationSupport\Headers`

Comment: @braX yes thanks very much. if you post it as an answer i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download it here: [The Acrobat X SDK](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/downloads.html)

Once you have unzip file, you will find a bunch of folders. You want to drill down to this folder:

```
\Acrobat 10 SDK\Version 1\InterAppCommunicationSupport\Headers
```

And look for the `acrobat.tlb` file there.

Add it to your references in the VB Editor by using Browse.

Once added, it will show up as `Adobe Acrobat 8.0 Type Library` - Which seems odd, since it's in a zip file named `Acrobat 10 SDK`, but that seems to do it.

Comment: Worked for me. Although, I couldn't see the file until I browsed for it in the VBE.

Comment: Scott, you probably have your system set up to not display hidden files. That is the default Windows setting. You can change that if you want to be able to see ALL files in File Explorer.

Comment: @braX Hi there, I added Adobe Acrobat 8.0 Type Library to the references, but it shows error while creating acrobat object. Im getting "activex component can't create object" when i try this code : "CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc") "

Comment: tried to navigate through the mentioned site but cannot find any download button. could you please help me out?

Comment: @smartini - When you open that page, do you see the "Next" button in the top right corner? Click that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library in one of my Excel sheets but could not locate it in any other Workbook so I saved the one it was in as a different book and copied all my data to the new book. The Adobe 10.0 Type Library worked just fine then.

So you might see if you have the Library in another book.