# Split PDF into new files per page - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to split a pdf into multiple new files per page.
I found this code on [Excel Forum](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1157046-split-pdf-file-into-individual-pages-using-vba.html#post5402470)
I modified it to to suit my folder path and file.
I have also added the Acrobat.tdl library to references.(Don't have the actual acrobat pro installed. Followed the steps suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352098/cant-find-the-adobe-acrobat-10-0-type-library-2020))

However, when I try to run the code, I get the error - Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.
The error occurs on the line `Set PDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.pdDoc")`

Here is the full code:

```
Sub SplitPDF()
  Dim PDDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc, newPDF As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
  Dim PDPage As Acrobat.CAcroPDPage
  Dim thePDF As String, PNum As Long
  Dim f As String, i As Integer, Result As Variant, NewName As String
  
  f = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
  thePDF = f & "CDE_9740240D_2020-09-08.pdf"
  
  Set PDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.pdDoc")
  Result = PDDoc.Open(thePDF)
  If Not Result Then
     MsgBox "Can't open file: " & thePDF
     Exit Sub
  End If
  
  '...
  PNum = PDDoc.GetNumPages
  
  For i = 0 To PNum - 1
    Set newPDF = CreateObject("AcroExch.pdDoc")
    newPDF.Create
    NewName = f & " Page_" & i & "_of_" & PNum & ".pdf"
    newPDF.InsertPages -1, PDDoc, i, 1, 0
    newPDF.Save 1, NewName
    newPDF.Close
    Set newPDF = Nothing
  Next i
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me make this code work.

Comment: You need to have acrobat installed.

Comment: @freeflow, Is there any other way I can achieve the splitting? By using any open source pdf library?