# Extract specific data points from pdf. Getting "Class not registered" error

Tags: vba

I am trying to search strings in pdf and extract data points after those strings. But I get "Class not registered" error in this line of code. The reference I use is Adobe Acrobat 8.0 Type Library
Please help. Thanks

```
If (objAvDoc.Open(strFilename, "")) Then
```

Syntax error in above line

```
Sub callFunc()

    getTextFromPDF ("C:\XXXXXX\XXXXX\6. CDS vs FA\052835022.pdf")

End Sub


Function getTextFromPDF(ByVal strFilename As String) As String
   Dim objAVDoc As New AcroAVDoc
   Dim objPDDoc As New AcroPDDoc
   Dim objPage As AcroPDPage
   Dim objSelection As AcroPDTextSelect
   Dim objHighlight As AcroHiliteList
   Dim pageNum As Long
   Dim strText As String

   strText = ""
   If (objAvDoc.Open(strFilename, "")) Then
      Set objPDDoc = objAVDoc.GetPDDoc
      For pageNum = 0 To objPDDoc.GetNumPages() - 1
         Set objPage = objPDDoc.AcquirePage(pageNum)
         Set objHighlight = New AcroHiliteList
         objHighlight.Add 0, 10000 ' Adjust this up if it's not getting all the text on the page
         Set objSelection = objPage.CreatePageHilite(objHighlight)

         If Not objSelection Is Nothing Then
            For tCount = 0 To objSelection.GetNumText - 1
               strText = strText & objSelection.GetText(tCount)
            Next tCount
         End If
      Next pageNum
      objAVDoc.Close 1
   End If

   getTextFromPDF = strText

End Function
```

Comment: At a glance, can see two parentheses opened in the if statement but closed only one.

Comment: After correcting syntax error I get "Class not registered" error on the code line stated above.
@Naresh

Comment: The function seem to be from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36270850/9808063). See if the library references are correct. I haven't tested the code.

Comment: @Naresh The references are correct. Not sure what went wrong

Comment: For reference [Link1 SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60356242/9808063) and [Link2 Adobe Support Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-sdk/how-to-download-acrobat-sdk-vba/m-p/10144295)

Comment: @Naresh Thanks for your reply. I understood that to get sdk running I need licensed version of Adobe Acrobat DC

Comment: Ohhh!! I didn't know/ read that. Thanks for the update.